# angular-google-maps fitBoundsAccessor abstract class example needed

Tags: angular, google-maps, directive, angular-google-maps

I am trying to use the fitBounds option in **agm-map** to auto-fit the google map to the available data.  I am doing something wrong; here is my code:

```
<div class="map">
  <agm-map [latitude]= "latitude" 
           [longitude]="longitude"
           [fitBounds]="true">

    <agm-data-layer [geoJson]="listOfPaths"
                    [style]="styleFunc" 
                    [agmFitBounds]="true">
    </agm-data-layer>

  </agm-map>
</div>
```

I am not doing anything else related to this implementation (i.e., no typescript associated), but I see in the [docs](https://angular-maps.com/api-docs/agm-core/directives/AgmFitBounds.html) that I'm supposed to "implement the FitBoundsAccessor abstract class". Can anyone provide an example of how to do this?

Here is the error:
*compiler.js:1021 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
No provider for FitBoundsAccessor ("
 -->
[ERROR ->]*

Answer (score 1):

The `fitBounds` directive only works on `agm-marker` and custom componenents - i.e. *not* on `agm-data-layer`!

To solve this you could wrap the `agm-data-layer` in a custom component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-agm-data-layer-wrapper',
  template: '<agm-data-layer></agm-data-layer>',
  styleUrls: ['./agm-data-layer-wrapper.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    AgmDataLayerWrapperComponent ,
    {provide: FitBoundsAccessor, useExisting: AgmDataLayerWrapperComponent}
  ],
})
export class AgmDataLayerWrapperComponent implements FitBoundsAccessor {

   ...

   getFitBoundsDetails$(): Observable<FitBoundsDetails> {
     // return the relevant coordinates here
   }
}
```

(Of course you'd need to forward the relevant inputs and outputs.)

Comment: There is also some relevant do here: https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/docs/content/guides/implement-auto-fit-bounds.md